# Merging 2 functions under one Private Sub

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to merge 2 different functions under one Private Sub but keep getting "Block If without End If" error. Cant seem to crack this. I've tried to make it work but keep getting same error?

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Fill in Date when checked.
Dim rngColJ As Range
Dim rngColA As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rngg As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set rngColJ = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("J:J"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 20

Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not rngColJ Is Nothing Then
    For Each Rng In rngColJ
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End If

Set rngColA = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 4

If Not rngColA Is Nothing Then
    For Each Rng In rngColA
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If

    Next
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't have a `Next` associated with `For Each Rng In WorkRng`.

Comment: You also don't have a `Next` associated with `For Each Rng In WorkRngg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a `Next` associated with `For Each Rng In WorkRng`.

Also note: your `Application.EnableEvents` is within the `If Not WorkRngg` block, so, structurally it looks like you've not matched your loop and if statements properly.

The problem right now is that the compiler is confused because your `For Each` loop is encountering an `End If` when it should be hitting a `Next`. Of course it doesn't *know* that, it just knows that what you have is syntactically incorrect.

Something like so:

```
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End If

If Not WorkRngg Is Nothing Then
    For Each Rngg In WorkRngg
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then  '<~~ possibly this should be (Rngg.Value)?
            Rngg.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rngg.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        Else
            Rngg.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If

    Next
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I'd also suggest finding a better naming convention than `Rng` and `Rngg`, etc. it's going to be easy to make difficult-to-troubleshoot typographical errors, as you *may* have done within the `For Each Rngg in WorkRngg` loop.

Since you're using `Rng` as an iterator, you don't need both. Just use `Rng` in both loops. You'd only need both variables if you were working with two different range's concurrently. so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Fill in Date when checked.
Dim rngColJ As Range
Dim rngColA As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rngg As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set rngColJ = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("J:J"), Target)
Set rngColA = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), Target)


Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not rngColJ Is Nothing Then
    xOffsetColumn = 20
    For Each Rng In rngColJ
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End If

If Not rngColA Is Nothing Then
    xOffsetColumn = 4
    For Each Rng In rngColA
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then  
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If

    Next
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed the initial problem, but now for both values entered in Column A and Column J it offsets 4 spaces and inputs a date. Whereas for values entered in Column A it should offset 4 and for Column J 20.

Comment: If you assign `xOffsetColumn = 20` and then two lines later `xOffsetColumn = 4`, what will the value of `xOffsetColumn` be on *literally any* subsequent line of code?

Comment: Its going to be `xOffsetColumn = 4`

Comment: Yes :D do you see what your problem is? And how to fix it?

Comment: Thanks for the light bulb comment lol yup definitely do now, i fixed it in the original. Also, I'm using `Rng` as an iterator is there a need to Dim `Rng` and `Rngg` ??

Comment: nah you definitely don't need both `Rng` and `Rngg` unless you are handling both objects concurrently (i.e., in a nested loop, or if there's any other consideration that would require using both at the same time). But strictly using as an iterator, in seperate iterations, you're OK to just use one like `Rng`.